# What is the use of Kernel updation?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

Now I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTE.What is the advantage over previous version if I updated to new Kernel update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer kernels have newer stuff. That's the basic answer.

Devices that might have come out after the kernel version Ubuntu 14.04 uses by default will be more likely to have included support in newer kernel versions.

For instance, the newer kernels have better graphics support for NVIDIA cards. The newer Intel processors actually newer Linux kernels to work properly. Pretty much anything newer than 2014 will need a newer kernel version.

Comment: after downloading from kernel.org(tar.xz),How to proceed?

Comment: @SriRam i wouldn't recommend manually installing a kernel from tar package.  Do `apt-cache search ^linux-image ` in terminal , select the name you want , and install using for example `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic` . The kernel images from `apt-get` go through testing and modification from Ubuntu developers, so it's best to use that